# How do I pause my main thread so my JFrame can operate properly

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, wait

I read a couple questions related to pausing main and both gave answers I didn't understand, and frankly I don't think are applicable.

I have a JFrame that makes use of a database I'm setting up in my driver class.

The JFrame will launch and the window opens; however when I try to make use of the database it fails; because back in main the program just keeps running and shuts down the connection, and closes it.

I tried just removing the connection.close() code just to see if my database methods work in the JFrame, and they do, so I just need to learn how to halt main while my JFrame is running.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File dbPropertiesFile = new File(DbConstants.DB_PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
        if (!dbPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            showUsage();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try {
            new Lab9(dbPropertiesFile).run(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            shutdown();
        }
    }

    private static void configureLogging() {
        ConfigurationSource source;
        try {
            source = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(LOG4J_CONFIG_FILENAME));
            Configurator.initialize(null, source);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    String.format("Can't find the log4j logging configuration file %s.", LOG4J_CONFIG_FILENAME));
        }
    }

    private static void shutdown() {
        LOG.info("Shutting down");
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void showUsage() {
        System.err.println(
                String.format("Program cannot start because %s cannot be found.", DbConstants.DB_PROPERTIES_FILENAME));
    }

    private Lab9(File file) throws IOException {
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
        database = new Database(properties);
    }

    /**
     * Where the computer start making a lot of noise.
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private void run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Running");

        LOG.info("Loading database properties from: " + DbConstants.DB_PROPERTIES_FILENAME + ".");
        LOG.info(properties.getProperty("db.driver"));
        LOG.info("Driver loaded");
        LOG.info("DB URL = " + properties.getProperty("db.url"));
        LOG.info("DB USER = " + properties.getProperty("db.user"));
        LOG.info("DB PASSWORD = " + properties.getProperty("db.password"));

        connect();

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        try {

            // If the user enters the -drop switch
            if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(DROP_COMMAND)) {
                LOG.info("Table " + CustomerDao.TABLE_NAME + "is being DROPPED!");
                customerDao.drop();
                LOG.info("Table has been DROPPED!");
            }

            // Check to see if the table is already made; if its not then make it, and fill
            // it.
            if (Database.tableExists(CustomerDao.TABLE_NAME) == false) {
                createTables(statement);
                LOG.info("Created the table: " + CustomerDao.TABLE_NAME + ".");
                LOG.info("Inserting Customer objects into table: " +  CustomerDao.TABLE_NAME + ".");
                insertCustomers();
                LOG.info("Inserted customer info into table from file: [" + CUSTOMER_DATA + "].");

            }

        createUI();

              // I NEED MAIN
              // TO STOP
              // AROUND HERE!

        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            connection.close();
        }
    }

    public static void createUI() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    DatabaseControlFrame frame = new DatabaseControlFrame(customerDao);
                    frame.setVisible(true);

                                       // OR MAYBE I NEED MAIN
                                       // TO STOP
                                       // AROUND HERE!

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });     
    }

    private void connect() throws SQLException {
        connection = database.getConnection();
        customerDao = new CustomerDao(database);
    }

}
```

Any ideas? I tried using a while(frame.isVisilbe()){     wait(600)    }; But the compiler had a spas when I tried to use wait().

You'll note I'm passing a customerDAO object to my JFrame constructor; but I'm beginning to wonder could I make a connection inside the JFrame so that when main's connection closes; my JFrame's doesn't? Is that a good idea? Is that even possible I'm not super SQL savvy I'm going to need to study up on it more.

Comment: *because back in main the program just keeps running and shuts down the connection,* - why would the main program shut down the connection. The main program should be the main program and just run forever until the user closes the frame. This is how GUI design works. You create a display a frame. The frame sits there waiting for the user to initiate an event by clicking on a button or something and then the code responds to the button.

Comment: @camickr I'm not sure in the try catch block the finally statement connection.close() will execute before I close the JFrame window when it pops up.

Are you suggesting I make it so the JFrame closes the connection?

Comment: *Are you suggesting I make it so the JFrame closes the connection?* - yes. How do you know when the user is finished making database queries? So the connection should stay open until the user closes the frame. Or you need to establish a new connection each time the user does a query and then close the connection. The point is the frame is the starting point for the application. A database query is just a function invoked by the user when working with the frame.

Comment: The only thing your main method should do is call the SwingUtilities invokeLater method to create the JFrame.  All database queries should happen in an ActionListener that is invoked when the user clicks on a JButton.   Read up on event-driven coding and go through the Oracle tutorial Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use Thread.sleep() - I've found that useful with JFrame before, though I'm not 100% sure it would fit what you're looking for. If you want it to wait indefinitely, put it in a while loop:

```
while(//condition)
{
    Thread.sleep(500); //pauses for .5 sec, then loops back to check condition
}
```

Comment: I tried using a while loop with the fram such as:    while frame.isVisible() and frame.isActive() But both of them seem to cause an inifinite loop and it freezes my JFrame making it unusable. I'm not really sure what kind of condition I would pass it other then what I've tried, any ideas?

Comment: You could try either a key listener or click listener - those have worked for me in the past. When I did it, I extended KeyAdapter in my own class, and then overrode the keyPressed method to send a boolean back to main, notifying it that the key had changed. I don't know if that's the best solution for you - it worked well for me because I was already using the listener for several other purposes, but otherwise it might be an overcomplication.

Answer (score 0):

`JFrame` event handler runs on a [different thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) than *main* thread, so you need to `shutdown` on that thread.

Here is a example, [Using JDBC with GUI API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/jdbcswing.html).

This example call `connection.close()` on [received window-closing-event](https://github.com/arashaga/jdbc-stuff/blob/master/src/com/oracle/tutorial/jdbc/CoffeesFrame.java#L80-L90).

```java
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    public MyFrame() {
        // ...
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {
                shutdown();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```